# Embeddings of graphs on surfaces

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I need your help in the next problem:

I use $N_g$, $g \geq 1$, to denote the nonorientable surface which can
be constructed by inserting $n$ cross-caps on the sphere (these cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

I need to show that if a simple graph $G$ is embedded in the nonorientable surface $N_g$, $g \geq 1$, then:

$$\chi(G) \leq \frac{7 + \sqrt{1 + 24g}}{2},$$

where $\chi(G)$ denotes the chromatic number of $G$.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know the analogous argument for orientable surfaces? how the euler characteristic relates to the chromatic number, and the euler characteristic for $N_g$? i believe the argument carries through the same, and you see why you lose the factor of two (for orientable surfaces it's $48g$)

Comment: Thanks ! but I don't know the analogous argument for orientable surfaces . .@exitingcorpse

Comment: it's the souped up version of euler's formula about the euler characteristic of a planar graph. you can find more information about the orientable generalisation here: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2012-13/2term/ma006b/12Ma6bChp35.pdf

Comment: Ok , thank you very much !